# Unable to copy file using Force-copy.ps1

Tags: powershell, cmd.exe, file-transfer

I can't copy my file from drive with bad sectors to healthy drive using your "force-copy.ps1" script when i try to copy this appears:-

```
PS C:\Users\ACER\desktop> .\Force-Copy.ps1 -SourceFilePath "J:\All Pictures In This Computer\New folder\FileBrowser\Videos\VID_20170619_155259.mp4" DestinationFilePath "C:\Users\ACER\Desktop"
C:\Users\ACER\desktop\Force-Copy.ps1 : Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'BufferSize'. Cannot
convert value "C:\Users\ACER\Desktop" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."
At line:1 char:143
+ ... \VID_20170619_155259.mp4" DestinationFilePath "C:\Users\ACER\Desktop"
+                                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Force-Copy.ps1], ParameterBindingArgumentTransformationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,Force-Copy.ps1
```

Comment: You will have to provide the source code to `Force-Copy.ps1` if you want our assistance.  It appears the script is expecting an integer value but you are providing a path.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at how you are calling the script:

`.\Force-Copy.ps1 -SourceFilePath "J:\All Pictures In This Computer\New folder\FileBrowser\Videos\VID_20170619_155259.mp4" DestinationFilePath "C:\Users\ACER\Desktop"`

I think you might be missing a hyphen (-) before `DestinationFilePath` and it is interpreting this as a variable, not a flag. You could try:

`.\Force-Copy.ps1 -SourceFilePath "J:\All Pictures In This Computer\New folder\FileBrowser\Videos\VID_20170619_155259.mp4" -DestinationFilePath "C:\Users\ACER\Desktop"`